# Resizing does not behave properly in libGDX with a ScreenViewport

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

I have been trying to get the simplest program going to get my marks and port my game to libGDX but unfortunately I cannot figure out what is happening. What I am trying to do is to get a Stage with a ScreenViewport and keep a blue square centered even after a resize. Here is the minimal code I am using:

Here is the Screen:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

private Stage stage;
private Tile tile;

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.draw();
    stage.act(delta);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    tile.setPosition(width / 2 - 25, height / 2 - 25);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    this.stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    this.tile = new Tile();
    tile.setSize(50, 50);
    stage.addActor(tile);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this.stage);
}
```

And now the Tile class:

```
public class Tile extends Actor {

private ShapeRenderer renderer = new ShapeRenderer();

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    batch.end();
    renderer.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
    renderer.setTransformMatrix(batch.getTransformMatrix());
    renderer.translate(getX(), getY(), 0);
    renderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    renderer.end();
    batch.begin();
}
```

There is no other code beside the `Game` class and a few stubs. I am getting the proper result but when I resize I sometimes land on a screen with a distorted blue rectangle that is not centered. As I resize it looks like it stretches the square for a bit then all of a sudden the square is repositioned correctly and it starts again. I have noticed that will all the different viewports I tried. They behave as they should but there is always this phase when things go wrong for a bit. I was using a texture before the blue square drawing and the result is the same.

I am hoping that someone will look at this and explain me the obvious because I am quite confused at the moment :)

Thanks

**EDIT:** I tried on another Mac running Yosemite and there the result is fine. It seems to be a setup issue...I tried Java 1.7 and 1.8 and it makes no difference.

Comment: You mean it's distorting as you resize the window (before releasing mouse button)? What platform are you running on? Usually, resize and render are not called while the window is being resized by user, only after the user releases the mouse button.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes this happens during the resize but what's strange is that when I release the mouse it gets stuck to how it looked like during the resize: stretched/offcentered. Also calling a render in the resize function doesn't seem to make it any better.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I forgot to mention, I am running this on MacOSX (Yosemite).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

create a private attr table :

```
private Table table;
```

in your show method :

```
table = new Table(skin); // if you have skin you add it if not u leave it blanc
```

add you title to the table (in your show method also) :

```
table.add(title) // here you can position your title where ever you want using table layout 
table.add(title).colspan(3).expandX().spaceBottom(50).row(); // exemple
```

now add the table to your stage instead of the title

```
stage.addActor(table);
```

then in your resize method :

```
@Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
        table.invalidateHierarchy();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was going to try it but it is apparently a setup issue on my machine since my code works fine on my laptop running the same OS.